# Ubuntu 21.10 suspension problems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, suspend

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 on a Lenovo Legion laptop:

- GNOME 40.4.0
- Windowing X11
- 15.5GB DDR3, 1.3TB HD
- Intel i7-9750 @ 2.6GHz + nV GTX 1660

This system recently forgot how to suspend - from both the power menu and by closing the lid. Here's the behavior I've observed thus far:

- screen blanks briefly, then renders the default (purple) Ubuntu login.
- mouse is functional. touchpad is not.
- login repeats the "blank then Ubuntu login" behavior, only this time no user name is displayed - only the password field.
- mouse is not functional. touchpad is not functional.
- ctrl-alt-delete relaunches Ubuntu to its normal bootup state.

I'm hoping that a new kernel install will solve this, but I'd rather know the root cause. Any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 NVIDIA 470/510 `nv_restore_user_channels` bug + workaround:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend/1391917#1391917